# Is there an option in Google Analytics to compare the Search Engine results for two different time ranges?

Tags: google-analytics

In the Google Analytics in the Search Engine Optimization there is an option to see all the queries that've been used to find the my page. I would like to create an custom report to compare two different date ranges (e.g. march 2014 compared to June 2014) and i would like to see and compare what was the Average Position/Impressions for one query durring March 2014 and what are the  values (average possition/impressions) for the same query for the current date.

Is there such an option in google analytics? or i need to export data from one date range and from another one and then use Excel/Google Spreadsheet to create such a report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar in which you select your timeframe has a compare option (which works with almost any report in GA). I assume that is what you mean ?

[image]